# How to handle IndexedDB with SSR (Remix)

Tags: indexeddb, remix, dexie

I am creating an application which handles some data which shouldn't be sent over the network. I am using IndexedDB via `dexie` and `dexie-react-hooks` to store the information in the browser so I can use it alongside the server-side stuff.

I am building the application on Remix. The problem arises when using IndexedDB with Remix server side rendering as IndexedDB doesn't exist on the server.

I have tried a couple things and arrived at one solution.

the database is created in a file called "database.ts" and exports a subclass of `Dexie`.

```js
// database.ts
import Dexie from 'dexie';

export interface DatabaseItem {
  id?: number;
  text: string;
}

export class TestDatabase extends Dexie {
  items!: Dexie.Table<DatabaseItem, number>;

  constructor() {
    super('test-database');
    this.version(1).stores({
      items: '++id',
    });
  }
}

export const db = new TestDatabase();

db.on('populate', async () => {
  await db.items.bulkAdd([{ text: 'one' }, { text: 'two' }, { text: 'three' }]);
});
```

I tried two things:

1. Leave `database.ts` named as-is, I get `Dexie.MissingAPIError` because IndexedDB doesn't exist on the server. This would require a server-side polyfill I think.
2. Change `database.ts` to `database.client.ts`, I then get a not defined error during initial page load because the variable exported (db) doesn't exist during initial server-side rendering (but is fine if navigating to the page).

```js
const items = useLiveQuery(() => db.items.toArray()); // db is not defined during initial render
```

The solution I have arrived at is to rename `database.ts` to `database.client.ts`, and use optional chaining on the `db` variable every time, it works, but that seems like a cludge as the db will exist after initial render.

```js
const items = useLiveQuery(() => db?.items.toArray());
```

I have a minimal example of option 3 here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-bdp5c7?file=app/routes/index.tsx

My question is: Is this correct? Is there a better solution like polyfill IndexedDB on the server-side so that initial rendering is fine and leave the data to the hydration on the client side?

Comment: Given that you need the data on the server side for correct initial rendering, it sounds like you should consider adding a database for the server, such as Redis, MongoDB or something similar? Or if the data is small in size, maybe it can be simplified by using cookies that are available both on server side and client side?